# How to scrolldown in react native?

Tags: react-native

I am using this :

```
    useEffect(() => {
            if (isChecked) {
         
           setTimeout(() => {
            
            window.scrollToEnd();
          }, 500);
        
              setIsChecked(false);
            }
          }, [ isChecked ]);


  return (
            <>
         {isChecked && 
              <View>
               <Text>Hello</Text>
              </View> 
           }
            
        </>
        )
```

If I don't use `setTimeout` it is not scrolldown but this is how it works. I think this is not efficient way. How to do better?

Comment: This library might help you out (https://github.com/nandorojo/react-native-anchors)